# How to Add Dependencies for Modular Maven Project in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, okhttp

I'm trying to explore open source project [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp).

I'm familiar with Maven, and understand how to debug/configure Maven projects in Eclipse, but this time things become weird to me.

The project imported from Github is already converted to Maven type, its POM utilizes *inheritance* as well as *aggregation* in the same time, I've no prior experience with such POM, **how do I suppose to add maven dependency library in Eclipse in this case?**

Things I've done but in vain:

- Maven > Update Project (not working)
- Maven > Select Maven Profiles > "All Activated"
- Project Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add Maven Managed Dependencies > Maven

Please help me!

[Here's the POM](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/pom.xml)

Comment: The OkHttp development team all uses IntelliJ. Might be worth trying that!

Comment: IntelliJ? it's a talk in our office. lol

Comment: I forget to call ```mvn eclipse:eclipse```